# Options for running data extraction on a daily basis

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an excel based data extraction method using power query and vba (for docs with passwords). Ideally this would be programmed to run once or twice a day.

My current solution involves setting up a spare laptop on the network that will run the extraction twice a day on its own. This works but I am keen to understand the other options. The task itself seems to be quite a struggle for our standard hardware. It is 6 network locations across 2 servers with around 30,000 rows and increasing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to work with increasing data, and you are going to dedicate a exclusive laptot for the process, i will think about install a database in the laptot (MySQL per example), you can use Access too... but Access file corruptions are a risk.
Download to this db all data you need for your report, based on incremental downloads (only new, modified and deleted info).

then run the Excel report extracting from this database in the same computer.

this should increase your solution performance.

probably your bigger problem can be that you query ALL data on each report generation.